# Spring_layout doesn't works properly with weights

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to use weights to define the distance between the nodes but it's not working. I even tried to use normalized values without success.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

raw_values = [(1,2, {'weight':70000000000}), (2,3,{'weight':700000}), 
                  (1,4,{'weight':1000000}), (2,4,{'weight':50000000000})]

normalized_values = []
for l in list1:
    norm_value = np.log10(l[2]['weight'])
    normalized_values.append((l[0], l[1], {'weight': norm_value}))

G.add_edges_from(raw_values)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw_networkx(G,pos)
edge_labels = nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos)

plt.show()
```

Here is the result I get, as you can see the nodes are very close even though the values are very different:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spring_layout` implements the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm, which models the graph as a system in which nodes repel each other. The repulsion is counteracted by springs that are placed between connected nodes.

The implementation in networkx has some issues, specifically with the repulsion term. This is evident in your example figure, where node 3 should never be at the center given that it is the least connected node.

However, your main grievance is with the attraction term. Basically, you defined extremely strong springs that are overcoming any repulsion term. As a consequence, the nodes are all bunched onto one point. When networkx returns these essentially random positions, the positions are rescaled to the bounding box implied by the `scale` and `center` parameters.

Your problem can be somewhat ameliorated by normalizing weights by their mean:

[image]

Note, however, that the small weight for edge (1, 4) (i.e. repulsion > attraction between 1 and 4) prevents nodes 1 and 4 being close to node 2, even though the weights for (2, 4) and (1, 2) are very large. In other words, the resulting layout is also constrained by the triangle inequality, and no normalization could possibly change that. Therefor, `spring_layout` will, in general, not be able to reflect all weights (the exception being trees and graphs where weights are actual geometric distances).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67116565/2912349
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

if __name__ == '__main__':

    edge_weights = {
        (1, 2) : 7_000_000_000,
        (2, 3) : 700_000,
        (1, 4) : 1_000_000,
        (2, 4) : 5_000_000_000,
    }

    G1 = nx.Graph([(source, target, {'weight' : w}) for (source, target), w in edge_weights.items()])
    pos1 = nx.spring_layout(G1)

    mean = np.mean(list(edge_weights.values()))
    G2 = nx.Graph([(source, target, {'weight' : w / mean}) for (source, target), w in edge_weights.items()])
    pos2 = nx.spring_layout(G2)

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    nx.draw_networkx(G1, pos1, ax=ax1)
    nx.draw_networkx(G2, pos2, ax=ax2)
    ax1.set_title('Raw')
    ax2.set_title('Normalized')
    ax1.axis('off')
    ax2.axis('off')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Exactly, good explanation! In my case I have a complete graph, so it's impossible, I could realize that after some time.

Comment: As much as I hate to say it, but for complete graphs, heatmaps or Hinton diagrams of the weights are often more informative than drawing the graph.

Comment: I wanted to show 3 data types at the same time, that's why I started using graph, I could use e.g. (1) edge thickness, (2) node color and (3) node size. With Hinton diagrams I would be able to represent just 2 data types, right? Also, do you have some advice to represent all this data? I'm thinking about just using a table maybe, or segment on sub graphs.

Comment: I think you should think first about the message that you would like to convey. At the moment, it seems that you simply want to capitalize on the fact that you have three different quantities that you would like to show simultaneously. I am sure that the actual message that you want to convey can be distilled further and then show in something simpler. For example, do you really need to show the full graph? Maybe you could show some example nodes and their immediate neighbours? Etc.